# PHP & SQL - Update query fails to update value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a very easy stock managing system. I'm able to show all the items in my table 'parts' and i'm showing the amount in a textbox. However, when i change the value from, for example, 0 to 5 in the textbox and i press my submit button, it doesn't update the stock.

Below is my code, i don't have alot of experience with update querys but i've read about it on php.net, obviously.

```
                      <?php
                  echo "<table width=\"800\" class=\"nieuws\">";
                    $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","lichtwinkel");
                    $p=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE product LIKE 1");

                    echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
                    echo "<tr><th></th><th>Onderdeel nummer</th><th>Eigenschappen</th><th>Prijs</th><th>Voorraad</th></tr>";

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($p)){
                      echo "<tr>";
                      echo "<td><img class='lamp' src='../css/images/".trim($row['partnr']).".png' alt='Geen afbeelding beschikbaar'></td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['partnr']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['specs']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>&euro; ".$row['price']."</td>";
                      echo "<td><input type='text' id='aantal' name='aantal' value=$row[voorraad] /></td>";
                      echo "<td><input type='submit' id='update' name='update' value='Update' /></td>";
                      echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";

                    if(isset($_POST['aantal']) && $_POST['update']) {
                      $y = $_POST['aantal'];
                      $p=mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE parts SET voorraad = '$y' WHERE partnr = $row[0]");
                    }

                    echo "</form>"
                  ?>
```

Simply said, what i'm trying to achieve is the following:
Whenever i change the value displayed in the texbox, and i press my submit button, i want it to update the value in the database.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? Any ideas? Articles i should read?
All help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: if `voorraad` field is string this will not work, second, your code is open for SQL injection., maybe this will work `"UPDATE parts SET voorraad = '$y' WHERE partnr = $row[0]"` but still SQL injection, try to debug `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: one more thing, this will also not work `echo "<td><input type='text' id='aantal' name='aantal' value=$row[voorraad] /></td>";` maybe this is the actual issue.

Comment: in last why are u connect twice in your code? no need

Comment: dont know about this `SELECT * FROM parts WHERE product LIKE 1` do u want to use LIMIT 1?

Comment: u r starting the `<form>` inside the loop and closed the form outside the loop.

Comment: If you are using php ver <= 5.3 you must put the `$row[0]` variable in your string inside `{...}`. Try this: `"UPDATE parts SET voorraad = $y WHERE partnr = {$row[0]}"`

Comment: @Dekel: i am 100% sure `$y` is a string

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, it isn't my native language. I know it's vulnerable for SQL injection, i haven't escaped anything properly, yet. Thanks for the tip though. I've changed my while loop, so it doesn't open any forms inside the loop and i only opent 1 connection instead of 2 to database, stupid mistake from my side. @devpro, why doesn't that input type text work while displaying and updating value? How do you mean?

Comment: @devpro, there are many problems there... this query is also out of the first `while` loop there..

Comment: @Dekel: yes like form inside the while with same name attributes...

Comment: I have updated the code in my post above.

Comment: thats good , now still not working???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i see, you were doing it wrong at all.

First you can't use form tag within more then one td element.

You were didn't close the form tag, only at end. (So if it loops 6 times, you will have 6 forms open, but one ended!).

At update, you're selecting row[0] - it's outside of loop with rows?

Even if you update it, it will show wrong results again. Update should be above selects! So it picks up newly updated value.

What to do:

1. First make one form for all updates.
2. Use your submit button to have value DATABASE_ID.
3. Make the name of "aantal" to "aantalDATABASE_ID".
4. At submit check for $_POST['update'], and use it's value (DATABASE_ID) to get input $_POST["aantal".$_POST['update']].
5. Do update, you have all you need.

Example:

```
<?php
echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
echo "<table width=\"800\" class=\"nieuws\">"   
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","lichtwinkel");

if(isset($_POST['update']) && !empty($_POST['update'])) {
    $y = $_POST['aantal'.$_POST['update']];
    $p=mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE parts SET voorraad = '".$y."' WHERE partnr = '".$_POST['update']."'");
    }

$p=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE product LIKE 1");
echo "<tr><th></th><th>Onderdeel nummer</th><th>Eigenschappen</th><th>Prijs</th><th>Voorraad</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($p)){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><img class='lamp' src='../css/images/".trim($row['partnr']).".png' alt='Geen afbeelding beschikbaar'></td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['partnr']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['specs']."</td>";
        echo "<td>&euro; ".$row['price']."</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' id='aantal' name='aantal".$row[0]."' value='".$row[voorraad]."' /></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' id='update' name='update' value='".$row[0]."' /></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo '</form>';
?>
```

After all, take care about SQL Injections. "aantal" value is user input. As the submit value can be changed.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I got it working now. But why do you use empty and isset? Is one safer to use then the other? I tried looking it up but don't really get that much information back. Sorry, I'm still a beginner in PHP.

Comment: isset just checks for variable is setted, but not it's value, with empty we checks is value empty (as we need it for update)